# Spams, Scams on WordPress site - what to do?

Tags: spam

Suddenly our hosting company complaint our boss with a google mail that saying something like:

> **Your site is full of spam/scam. Please remove such malicious thing or we will unlist your site.**

That made us crazy. We found some links in our WordPress site is taking us to a page, that is obviously NOT our site-page. But with the same URL of our page (domain/my-page) it's showing someone other's contents - that's disturbing too.

We tried the cPanel's "Virus Scanner" to find any trace of virus attack to the site, but found nothing.

Then, one of our developer found a way to generate a new page for the content of that page with a slightly different slug, and that worked. But after days it's worthless.

How can we get rid of such spam/scam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of our developer Mr. Ahsan Ullah found a very normal solution to that: He simply **Refreshed the Permalink settings** and it's all set.

From `/wp-admin`, going `Settings` » `Permalinks`, he clicked the <kbd>**Save Changes**</kbd> button. The permalink structure of the whole site was refreshed and the unwanted links were vanished from the site.